What is wrong with my young magnolia? Please help
I have a young magnolia tree whose leaves started turning brown on the edges. I am fertilising it (is this a mistake?) with a fertiliser that contains nitrogen. Could it be that there is too much salt in the soil as a result? It is early July here in cold England, but we have had some hot days. It's sheltered from the rain and I may need to water it more. The leaves feel soft and there seem to be some flower buds on the tree now. I'm sorry I could not figure out how to add images from my phone. Will try from my laptop. Thank you for any advice!!

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

It's exceedingly easy to overfertilize trees. So it's often a mistake.

On my phone, I attach the pic to an email. Then on laptop, I go into the draft email (no need to send) and copy the image and paste it into the post or answer.
